# How to check if 'Double amount = new Double(JOptionPane......)' is empty

Tags: java, if-statement, double

I've looked in vain on Stack and the rest of the web for a way to determine whether or not the following is empty:

```
Double amount = new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the amount (numeric only):"));
```

I've tried:

```
if (amount.equals(null)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Cancelled!");
    }
```

But that's not catching it. I'm getting this at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:608)
at CurrencyConversion.main(CurrencyConversion.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: exactly what it says: showInputDialog is returning an empty string...

Comment: I get what you're saying, but how do I catch that showInputDialog is taking an empty string and trying to parse it to a double?

Comment: @SmittyWerbenJägerManJensen you're not parsing or casting it to a double.

Comment: @Fleuv -- you're not? I thought that the showInputDialog accepted a string ("behind the scenes") and parsed that input to a double? I just assumed from:   `at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)`

Comment: @SmittyWerbenJägerManJensen I guess you're right. It actually was a wild guess of me. Should've prepended the word "maybe" to my comment.

Comment: `String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the amount (numeric only):"); if(!answer.isEmpty()) { double amount = Double.parseDouble(answer); }`

Comment: Nailed it, thanks!